# LOST.DIR on my SD card contains 98 years old files

Tags: sd-card

I was cleaning up my SD card and find LOST.DIR i knew what it was for but i did not understand why the hell there are 98 YEARS old files

Does someone have got an explain?
I´m kinda scared

Comment: there is only one possible explanation - you are a time traveler when you asleep. Dharma Initiative released the nanobot cloud which deleted your memory

Comment: Lol i think that is kinda imposible

Answer (score 0):

Take a sheet of paper and a pen.
Write down the following sentence:

*"My birthday is 01/01/1924"*

You can see there is nothing mysterious on that paper. just because it is written somewhere it doesn't mean it is true.

LOST.DIR is collection directory for restored garbage from corrupt files which is created when `fsck_msdos` is trying to repair your MicroSD Card.

imagine directory is like a folder and each file is a sheet of paper. access to folder is restricted (some room only your family has the key). each paper/file has three timestamps

- `mtime` - *modify time* is time of birth/update of file (data) itself
- `ctime` - *change time* is time of file permissions (day your mother gave you the key)
- `atime` - *last access time* (so your father knows the exact date when your hands touched the sheet of paper or you read it's content with your eyes)

the timestamp `mtime` of files can be set to any value independently of "current" date/time. even the "current" time `hwclock` of your phone itself can be set to any date if you want so.

---

Why it is 98 years can be coincidence or set intentionally. The question can not be answered without knowing the origin of that files.

If it happens too often (every day) and there is again lot of data inside LOST.DIR even after deleting, that might indicate your MicroSD Card is near end of life and will become unreadable soon

Comment: Wow! You realy scared me about my sd card ending.

Anyway thanks for help i just readed the files that have been placed here and they are images of "FixingWER" (Old smartphone fixing company) but it is creepy cuz the files are kinda glichy (Black sqares everywhere). Thanks for the help